# Changing the Variable Pitch Font

Tags: faces, variable-pitch

Is there a way to change the font associated with the variable-pitch-mode? On my emacs installation enabling variable-pitch-mode changes the font to a sans-serif font; I would like to use a serif font instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that function `variable-pitch-mode` hard-codes the use of face `variable-pitch`.  I think your two choices (other than perhaps advising that function) are these:

1. *Use face* `variable-pitch`.  Just customize it to be have any appearance you want: `M-x customize-face variable-pitch`.
2. *Write your own command*, similar to `variable-pitch-mode`.  That definition is very short.  You need only substitute your own face for face `variable-pitch` in that definition.  (You could also define your command using `buffer-face-mode-invoke`, which is what `variable-pitch-mode` uses.)

   For example:

```el
    (defun my-variable-pitch-mode (&optional arg face)
      "MY Variable-pitch default-face mode.
    An interface to `buffer-face-mode' which uses FACE
    \(`variable-pitch', by default).
    Besides the choice of FACE, it is the same as `buffer-face-mode'."
      (interactive (list (or current-prefix-arg 'toggle)))
      (buffer-face-mode-invoke face arg (called-interactively-p 'interactive)))
```

In fact, I'll (or you can) suggest that as the definition of `variable-pitch-mode`, using `M-x report-emacs-bug`.  (I've done that now - bug #[24594](http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=24594).)

Comment: Wonderful. I didn't know how `variable-pitch-mode` worked; thank you for explaining it to me. I personally am fine with customizing the `variable-pitch` face, but I agree that it makes sense to have the option to change the face associated with `variable-pitch-mode`, so I hope that functionality gets added eventually.

Comment: Doesn't look like it will. But if customizing the face is all you need here, then that's good.