# Variable-pitch and fixed-pitch with the same font-size?

Tags: org-mode, fonts

I've learned [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/27525/changing-the-variable-pitch-font) that I can customize my variable-pitch font.
For org-mode, I'm using that customization together with the following snippet to get a mix of variable and fixed-pitch fonts:

```
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook
            '(lambda ()
               (variable-pitch-mode 1)
               (mapc
                (lambda (face)
                  (set-face-attribute face nil :inherit 'fixed-pitch))
                (list 'org-code
                      'org-link 
                      'org-block
                      'org-table
                      'org-block-begin-line
                      'org-block-end-line
                      'org-meta-line
                      'org-document-info-keyword))))
```

Everything except for normal text is displayed in fixed-pitch, which is displayed with variable-pitch. The problem with my solution is that the **font-size for both fonts is different and the variable-pitch looks really small and hard to read.** How can I adapt my solution so that both fonts have the same size?

(I also have the feeling that my solution is not ideal because I get buffer fontification problems every now and then in SRC blocks when opening files..)

Example image:

[image: different-fonts]

Answer (score 2):

This may or may not be what you are asking for, but if you set the `:height` property (i.e. font size) on `default` to some integral size, then you set the `:height` property on `variable-pitch` to a fractional value and it will be interpreted as a scaling factor applied on the parent face.